# PHP form input field and shadow-root (user agent)

Tags: html, shadow-dom

I was working with PHP and MySQL to create a page to get input and also display the result in the input field as well.
I've inserted some dummy data into the db for testing purpose but then I realized the value won't show up:

---

[image: sample2]

---

And while using inspect element I found this:

[image: sample]

I've browsed through a few websites and found out that this is some encapsulation method (shadow DOM) for HTML and only content inside the "inner-editor" div will be shown/render. For my case right now, how can I populate the value in it or maybe is there anyway not to use the shadow-root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect, mate. The proper attribute name should be **value**, not **valueS**. This is the reason why the input is not filled, the shadow-root has nothing to do with your problem.

P.S. I think you are also using a closing tag, where one simply closed it like this:

`<input ... />`

Comment: Or just omit the slash and the closing tag.  xhtml just isn't as popular these days; you can also get rid of your " quotes around simple attributes.